# C# constructor shortcut needed

Tags: c#

I have two classes:

```
public class PageMeta
{
    public PageMeta() { }
    public string DataSource { get; set; }
    public string TopicID { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }

}

public PersonViewModel()
{
    PageMeta = new PageMeta
    {
        Title = "Test"
    };
    public PageMeta PageMeta { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following code to create these:

```
var r = new PersonViewModel();
r.PageMeta.DataSource="abc";
r.PageMeta.TopicID="def";
```

In real life my classes are more complicated and this is just an example. What I would like to do is to combine the creation of the PersonViewModel with the setting up of the DataSource and TopicID.

```
var r = new PersonViewModel {
   PageMeta.DataSource="abc";
   PageMeta.TopicID="def";
}
```

Is there any way that this could be done in C# ?

Comment: Is PersonViewModel() supposed to be a class or a method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
var r = new PersonViewModel {
    PageMeta = {
        DataSource = "abc",
        TopicID = "def"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Slaks - Is there some way that I could do this without replacing the original ctor. Also still getting the syntax error related to TopicID line

Comment: This does not replace the original ctor.  Even though it has an `=`, it doesn't replace the existing `PageMeta` instance.  It doesn't give me any syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry about that. Now I see the =    Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can have an object initializer inside of another object initializer:

```
       var r = new PersonViewModel 
       {
            PageMeta = { DataSource = "abc", TopicID = "def" }           
       };
```

This works because your `PersonViewModel` constructor initializes `PageMeta` to a new instance.  Thus this initializes the fields of `PageMeta` property utilizing the `get` for `PageMeta`.

If you don't initialize a new instance of `PageMeta` in your constructor for `PersonViewModel` (or if `PageMeta` was a `struct` which returns a copy, so getter won't work) you'd access it through the `PageMeta` setter instead:

```
       var r = new PersonViewModel 
       {
            PageMeta = new PageMeta { DataSource = "abc", TopicID = "def" }           
       };
```